# No funciona menú hamburguesa en Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, menú, firefox, animated

Estoy implementando un menú  con CSS y JQuery. El caso es que me funciona perfectamente Safari y Chromium, pero en Firefox no me funciona el .animate que reescala el logo haciéndolo más pequeño cuando pulso el botón hamburguesa ni el propio menú hamburguesa se transforma en X, en css tengo los webkits correspondientes. Tengo que mencionar que estoy usando Bootstrap 3.3.7 pero eso no debería afectar a la ejecución.

Os dejo las imágenes GIF que ilustran bien el problema.

Chromium ejecuta bien el código (Safari también lo ejecuta así).
[image: Aquí se aprecia como Chromium ejecuta bien el código]

El fallo en Firefox
 [image: Fallo de Firefox]

Código HTML referenta al navbar:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="animated-icon1">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" id="mybrand">
       <p><img src="img/miT.png" alt="Logo Toni" id="mylogo">
       <span id="textomylogo">oni RZV</span></p>
    </a>
```

Código CSS que controla a la hamburguesa:

```
    .animated-icon1, .animated-icon2, .animated-icon3, .animated-icon4 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animated-icon1 span, .animated-icon3 span, .animated-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-icon1 span {
    background:var(--colorE);
}

.animated-icon3 span {
    background: var(--colorE);
}

.animated-icon4 span {
    background:#2F2D2D;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

/* Icon 3*/

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(2), .animated-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 11px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Icon 4 */

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 8px;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 21px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

Código JS

```
    var myLogoSize = function(){
    if (flagLogo==true) {
        $('#mylogo').animate({ width: '35px'},'slow');
                flagLogo=false; 
                }
     else {
        $('#mylogo').animate({width: '50px'},'slow');
                flagLogo=true;
        }
    }


$(function(){
    //Animación icono menú.
    $('.animated-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        myLogoSize();
    });
}
```

Comment: podrias colocar toda la informacion , ya que ejecute tu navbar y todo y no funciona nada. Ni si quiera el snippet lo muestra.

Comment: Ha sido resuelta y la información aportada era más que suficiente. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `Firefox v59.0 (64bits) on Windows 10` lo que pude ver es que al hacer `clic` sobre el elemento `<div class="animated-icon1"` no ocurre nada, este se debe a que **el elemento no es `clicable`**.

### Solución:

Si el evento `click` lo suscribimos al `<button`, todo funciona correctamente.

#### Código:

```
$(function() {
  //Animación icono menú.
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.animated-icon1').toggleClass('open');
    myLogoSize();
  });
})
```

#### Demo:

```js
var flagLogo = false;
var myLogoSize = function() {
  if (flagLogo == true) {
    $('#mylogo').animate({
      width: '35px'
    }, 'slow');
    flagLogo = false;
  } else {
    $('#mylogo').animate({
      width: '50px'
    }, 'slow');
    flagLogo = true;
  }
}


$(function() {
  //Animación icono menú.
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.animated-icon1').toggleClass('open');
    myLogoSize();
  });
})
```

```css
.animated-icon1,
.animated-icon2,
.animated-icon3,
.animated-icon4 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animated-icon1 span,
.animated-icon3 span,
.animated-icon4 span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.animated-icon1 span {
  background: var(--colorE);
}

.animated-icon3 span {
  background: var(--colorE);
}

.animated-icon4 span {
  background: #2F2D2D;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -60px;
}

.animated-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}


/* Icon 3*/

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10px;
}

.animated-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 20px;
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 11px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.animated-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 11px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}


/* Icon 4 */

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 20px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 8px;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animated-icon4.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 21px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-header">
  <button id="button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="animated-icon1">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" id="mybrand">
    <p><img src="img/miT.png" alt="Logo Toni" id="mylogo">
      <span id="textomylogo">oni RZV</span></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto!